# Javascript While loop integers

Tags: javascript

I have to create a while loop displaying the integers from 1-20 but only 5 integers per line.
I can't get the 5 integers per line part. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Have you even try this yourself?

Comment: yes but not like the way you had it. as you might have noticed from my question my coding right now is rather basic

Comment: I'm asking because posting your pieces of code may work better from learning point-of-view. You'll be able to understand which mistakes you made, how to avoid it in future, etc. In similar "hello-world" exampled that could be not so obvious, but IMO it always better to post something you did yourself.

Comment: I agree with elmigranto, try posting what you have so people can provide a solution AND help you with your own code. I understand being new to this though. At the very least, ask questions on the answers if you have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that builds a string and displays an alert box with the result.

```
var i = 0, result = "";

while (i++ < 20) {
    result += i + " ";

    // check to see if we're at 5/10/15/20 to add a new-line
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
        result += "\n";
    }
}

alert(result);
```

jsFiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/willslab/KUVkX/3/

Comment: I cleaned up the code very slightly. Thank you for accepting, let me know if you have any questions about the code.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's the next item after a multiple of 5 and if the current item is not the first item. If it is, also print out a newline. For example:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
     print(i); // Or however you're outputting it

     if(i % 5 === 1 && i > 1) {
         print('\n');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do...

```
if ( ! (i % 5)) {
    // Create new line.
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwy4h/).

Answer (score 0):

See no `while` loops in previous answers =)

```
function generateLine(start, nElements, separator) {
  var i = start;
  var range = [];
  while (range.length < nElements) range.push(i++);
  return range.join(separator) + '\n';
}

function generate(start, end, elementsInLine, inlineSeparator) {
  var lines = [];
  while (start < end) {
    lines.push( generateLine(start, elementsInLine, inlineSeparator));
    start += elementsInLine;
  }

  return lines.join('');
}

console.log( generate(1, 20, 5, ' ') );
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, I thought of writing a generic function as well. I wasn't sure it would be easy enough to understand though.